# How to write a port scanner listening for 'ACK' in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, port-scanning

please can anyone help me with the port scanner program to scan ports on the IP address provided,for ACK. i want to know the technique used to scan for ACK & use multi-threading so please help me in that perspective.

Thank you

Comment: If you search google for "Python port scanner" you can find links to such information. why don't you start with that and see how it goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a heads-up - Windows XP SP2 and later disable raw sockets, so you won't be able to scan for TCP ACK messages specifically on Windows. Since an ACK message is the last message in establishing a TCP connection, you can implicitly detect the ACK message by attempting to establish a connection with a simple `socket.connect` call (if it connects, you've sent your ACK).

If you want to see an example of a multithreaded port scanner that I wrote, see `inet.py` and `scanner.py` in [jaraco.net](http://bitbucket.org/jaraco/jaraco.net/src/tip/jaraco/net/).

Answer (score 1):

this is a multi-threaded port scanner i wrote

http://appusajeev.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/optimized-port-scanner-with-threading/

theres no way to track ACKs though.